# Cómo revierto un archivo que fue pusheado?

Tags: git, gitlab

Soy bastante nuevo con git y tengo esta duda
En el commit tengo tres archivos , por ejemplo

**ArchivoA,ArchivoB,ArchivoC**

Este commit fue pusheado al servidor y ahora necesito revertir los cambios realizados  solamente del **ArchivoA**

No tengo idea de como hacerlo para solo un archivo sin que me afecte los demas teniendo en cuenta que ya se encuentran en el servidor

Espero se haya entendido

Comment: Puedes hacer un nuevo commit en el que los cambios en ArchivoC lo dejen como estaba antes, y hacer un push de eso. Al clonar (o hacer pull) el repositorio el usuario verá sólo la última versión de ArchivoC. El problema es que la versión previa aún estará también en el historial y sería posible acceder a ella. ¿Pretendes eliminarla también de la historia? Eso sería más complejo pero puede hacerse

Comment: Intenta con ```git checkout -- ARCHIVO.js``` y cuando compruebes que esta como quieres vuelve a hacer push

Comment: Creo que podrías usar [git revert](https://www.atlassian.com/es/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/git-revert).